# Toggle style:display only works when style is in HTML not in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having trouble when appropriately moving CSS styles to CSS page. My original page that worked just fine:

```
<span class="faq-answer" data-category="<%=category %>" data-index="<%= i %>" style="display:none;"><%= a %></span>

function toggleVisible(category, index) {
  var select_answer = '.faq-answer[data-category="' + category + '"][data-index="' + index + '"]';
  var current_display = $(select_answer)[0].style.display;
  if (current_display === "none") {
    $(select_answer)[0].style.display = "block"
    $('.faq-question[data-category="' + category + '"][data-index="' + index + '"]')[0].style.paddingBottom="10px"
  } else if (current_display === "block") {
    $(select_answer)[0].style.display = "none"
    $('.faq-question[data-category="' + category + '"][data-index="' + index + '"]')[0].style.paddingBottom="0px"
  };
}
```

However, once I put the `style="display:none"` into a CSS file like so:

```
.faq-answer {
  display:none;
}
```

The JS then stops working to toggle the display on and off. Whay is this?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle link?

Comment: As mentioned by DevPat, go to http://jsfiddle.net. Sounds like a inheritance issue of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.style` contains the styles for inline styles, not ones from CSS stylesheets. You will need to use [jQuery("element").css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) or [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) to get the value

**JQuery css method**

```js
var dispVal = jQuery(".faq-answer").css("display");
console.log(dispVal);
```

```css
.faq-answer {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-answer"><div>
```

**getComputedStyle**

```js
var ele = document.querySelector(".faq-answer");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
console.log(style.display);
```

```css
.faq-answer {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-answer"></div>
```

You could also more simply use [.is(":visible")](http://api.jquery.com/is/) which will return a boolean value, true if visible, false if not.

```js
var isVisible = $(".faq-answer").is(":visible"); ;
console.log(isVisible);
```

```css
.faq-answer {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-answer"><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is looking at `style` attribute of the element. If you are going to use classes instead of styles, create two different classes and toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
<span class="faq-answer" data-category="<%=category %>" data-index="<%= i %>" class="faq_answer"><%= a %></span>

function toggleVisible(category, index) {
  var select_answer = '.faq-answer[data-category="' + category + '"][data-index="' + index + '"]';
  var isDisplayed = !$(select_answer)[0].hasClass("faq-answer");
  if (!isDisplayed) {
    $(select_answer)[0].removeClass('faq-answer');
    $('.faq-question[data-category="' + category + '"][data-index="' + index + '"]')[0].style.paddingBottom="10px"
  } else {
    $(select_answer)[0].addClass('faq-answer');
    $('.faq-question[data-category="' + category + '"][data-index="' + index + '"]')[0].style.paddingBottom="0px"
  }
}
```

Hope it is what you are looking for !

Comment: You should explain what you have changed and why.

Comment: I voted your comment. What happens is explained clearly in your comment and I suggested on adding/removing .faq-answer class.